Share blazor dialogs across projects within the same solution
I have a solution with multiple .NET 8 Blazor projects, including a class library used to share common code.
Solution
- Project 1
- Project 2
- SharedLibrary

Now I'd like to share Blazor dialogs. My Blazor projects use MudBlazor for UI. For some reason, this doesn't work:

Dialog is in Project 1 --> Dialog can be reused within Project 1, not Project 2
Dialog is in Project 2 --> Dialog can be reused within Project 2, not Project 1
Dialog is in SharedLibrary --> Dialog cannot be used by any Blazor project.

My IDE doesn't show any warnings until the code is compiled. I get this error:

Error CS0246 : The type or namespace name 'CreateNewFolder' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Both Project 1 and Project 2 reference the project SharedLibrary and I do have a using statement on the top of the Navigation menu, where the dialog is supposed to be called from:
@using SharedLibrary.Shared

This method is calling the dialog:
private void ShowNewFolder(MouseEventArgs _obj)
{
    ShowNewFolderDialog = true;
    var options = new DialogOptions { CloseOnEscapeKey = true,  MaxWidth = MaxWidth.Medium };
    DialogService.ShowAsync<CreateNewFolder>("Create New Folder", options);
}  

I tried finding relevant question but cannot find anybody having the same issue. Most like I'm missing something very basic.
Would somebody please be so kind to explain what I'm supposed to do so I can share dialogs across projects?

Your class library needs to be a Razor Class Library. Until it is you won't be able to use components inside of it. Once it is you will need to add the proper using directive which I normally do inside of Imports which might look something like this: @using global::SharedLibary.Components

amazing, thank you!

as mentioned by @Jilael, the solution was to add a Razor Class Library to share UI code within the solution
